# getDocumentByKey with view category separated by "\\" in XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I got a view where the fist column is categorized by one field and the second column is categorized with more values separated with "\".

I now try to get a document by key, it does not work until I remove the category option from the second column. I tried getEntryByKey, getAllEntriesByKey, getDocumentByKey, getAllDocumentsByKey in SSJS and in Java. I tried it just for fun with an LotusScript Agent and it works.

Another way that works is createViewNavFromCategory. But I also have some views where the first column is only sorted and of cause than this solution does not work for me.

Is that an known issue? Is there a way to work around this problem?

UPDATE:
I just want to use the first column for getDocumentByKey

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying in a Java agent. If that doesn't work, I'd raise a PMR. There are some differences between Java and LotusScript, so it's possible that it doesn't work. I found a similar inconsistency with number values (which should be fixed in 9.0.2, I believe) http://www.intec.co.uk/apparent-java-getalldocumentsbykey-getallentriesbykey-bug/

It may be that "\" gets escaped in Java, so you may need extra characters, same as you would in Formula Language

Comment: It's very strange, because i only work with the first column. I'm not sure what the server try to do this the second column.

Comment: @Pixel did you ever find what was the issue?

Comment: I created a PMR. IBM can recreate the Problem but there is still no fix.