# getDocumentByKey with a number vector doesn't find the document

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a 2 column sorted view and try to get a document the following code:

```
        var searchArr = new java.util.Vector();
        searchArr.addElement(10000310);
        searchArr.addElement(45);

        var customerdoc:NotesDocument = viw.getDocumentByKey(searchArr,true);
```

but the result is null. 
If I use only the first element for the key (10000310), then I get (the first) doc with that key. But with the 2-element-vector the lookup returns null. 
the same in LotusScript works fine:

```
Dim searchkey(1) As Double
searchkey(0) = 10000307
searchkey(1) = 45
Set doc = luview.Getdocumentbykey(searchkey, true)
```

gives me the document I need.

Confusing, for me ....
Uwe

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, hopefully to be fixed in 9.0.2. See this question [getDocumentByKey with view category separated by "\\" in XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605030/getdocumentbykey-with-view-category-separated-by-in-xpages)

Answer (score 0):

Your LS example uses an array, not a Vector. I am not even sure if it is intended to work with a Vector - never did that. So just use an array here, too, as the key.

Comment: Vector should be right http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_View_getDocumentByKey.html